# why I don't get a field with errors? Michael Hartl Tutorial ch. 7.3.3

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I filled in all the files as indicated in the listings, but I don't get an error field when I enter invalid data.
I have restarted rails server several times, but nothing has changed.
Tests with invalid data pass as needed.

my "app/views/users/new.html.erb" file:

```
<% title "Sign up" %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

my "app/controllers/users_controller.rb" file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      #
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

my "app/models/user.rb" file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEXP = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEXP },
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

and my "app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb" file:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

[tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G81vT.png)
and when I click "Create my account" this just refresh page

upd: I carefully checked my code with the code from the repository of Michael Hartl, but I didn't find anything strange, maybe something has changed in the gems that I use.

Comment: Have you got the css styling right for the error_explanation div and the alert alert-danger css classes? css names are normally hyphenated rather than underscored so I would have expected error_explanation to be error-explanation, regardless of this you should still see output from the errors array. It might be an idea to log output of the `@user` object in your controller action to the console to check the state of the `@user` object.

Comment: I would also use a local variable in the errors partial and pass the object through from the view in the call to `render` as this would make your shared partial usable for any object rather than only for a user

Comment: What does your controller and model look like?

Comment: Do you have the needed validations in your model/user.rb?

Comment: yes, I think I filled out the css file correctly, but even when I change something there, I can't see the changes associated with the error field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one repository I found a solution for rails version 7, in rails 5 everything worked with the code I provided above, but in version 7, in order for the error field to be displayed, you need to add an HTTP status code.
Adding `status: :unprocessable_entity` after `render 'new'` in the controller file solved my problem.